# How to create a weighted task cookie in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, todo

Task cookies are a [cool feature](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/35572/388) in org-mode that I use everyday to quickly check my progress when doing todo lists

e.g

```
- Grandparent Task [50%]
  - [-] Parent Task [80%]
    - [X] Child Task 1
    - [X] Child Task 2
    - [X] Child Task 3
    - [X] Child Task 4
    - [ ] Child Task 5
  - [X] Parent Task [100%]
    - [X] Child Task 1
    - [X] Child Task 2
```

Is there a way to add a weight to task cookie to show relative effort automatically?